# Mysterious error when naming a variable "goto"?

Tags: java

I tried to write some trivial code that concatenates two strings and prints them:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String goto = "jon skeet";
        System.out.println("the go-to guy for java questions is " + goto);
    }
}
```

But it gets all these errors:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:3: not a statement
        String goto = "jon skeet";
        ^
A.java:3: ';' expected
        String goto = "jon skeet";
              ^
A.java:4: illegal start of expression
        System.out.println("the go-to guy for java questions is " + goto);
                                                                    ^
A.java:4: ';' expected
        System.out.println("the go-to guy for java questions is " + goto);
                                                                        ^
4 errors
```

Why?

Comment: this is visible in your the code you posted, see how that word has a different color, that is used on reserved keywords :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`goto` is a reserved keyword in Java and cannot be used as a variable name, although it does not do anything.

Quote from the [JLS 3.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9):

> 50 character sequences, formed from ASCII letters, are reserved for use as keywords and cannot be used as identifiers (§3.8).

(`goto` is on this list)

> The keywords `const` and `goto` are reserved, even though they are not currently used. This may allow a Java compiler to produce better error messages if these C++ keywords incorrectly appear in programs.

Comment: +1 for the second quote. Didn't that this was the reason.

Answer (score 8):

`goto` is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) in Java although it is not used for anything.

Comment: +1 for clarifying that it cannot be used for anything.

Comment: I think they just reserved it when they started developing just in case they might implement a goto feature later on.

Comment: @André I strongly hope they don't though

Answer (score 4):

`goto` is one of [Java's reserved keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) and cannot be used as a variable name, just like `private`, `do`, `for`, `if`, etc. I attached a link, so please visit.

`goto` was never implemented to do anything, but nevertheless the keyword was reserved because of the possibility that sometimes in the future its functionality might be implemented. In language **C** and C-like languages, `goto` statement changes control flow and jumps to a desired label.

Answer (score 0):

goto is a reserved word which means you can not use this as variable name.

Here is wiki definition of reserved word

> In a programming language, a reserved word (also known as a reserved
>   identifier) is a word that cannot be used as an identifier, such as a
>   name of a variable or function or a labels; this is a syntactic
>   definition, part of the lexical grammar of identifiers

see the complete list of java reserved words  here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords

Comment: 2 errors with your post: 1) `goto` is the word, not `GoTo` (see your link for reference). 2) you can not.   EDIT: 1) fixed, 2) fixed

Comment: Corrected it. It was typo :(

Comment: removed my downvote. just wanted to make sure people know it's a typo until you corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Like all the others Java's reserved keyword, `goto` cannot be used as variable name.

You can see all reserved keyword [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).